# Azure VNet peering with Private Link

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns

So here is my scenario that I am trying to implement and need some help.

I have two VENT one for Virtual machine and another for Storage account. Both VNET have been peared successfully. Storage account have been disable public access and has Private Link enabled with Private DNS zone.

Now when I do nslookup on storage account from VM(in different network then storage account) it returns the public ip address and my understanding is I should be getting the private IP address which have been assigned in the Private DNS zone.

Am I incorrect with my understanding or am I supposed to do something extra which I haven't done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting private IP addresses.  Have you verified that both VNets are linked to the private DNS Zone?  Go to the Private DNS Zone in the Azure portal and verify the proper VNets are linked in "Virtual network links"

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cloudlady for the detailed response. We did come across with this solution but the problem is we have multiple resource group with VNET having storage account and can't implement this solution. For e.g VM is VNET1, SA1 in VNET2 and SA2 in VNET3. We can only associate VNET1 with Private DNS under for SA1 or SA2(by the way we have Private DNS for each SA in different Resource Group) Also what we noticed that even if it gives public IP address we can do all the operation on storage account with public access disabled. We think its because of successful paring.

Comment: Another follow up question would be if the storage account's public access is disable(blob anonymous access disabled) and nslookup returns public ip address how we are able to perform operations(upload blob/create container) on storage account from VM?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati you need a centralized/authoritative DNS if you want to share the private IP addresses.  To the best of my knowledge it would not be related to VNet peering.  The only other solution with your setup would be to do manual ARecord updates for the storage account in the other private DNS Zone.  I would not recommend this.

Comment: Yeah that was one of the solution we are also thinking but I have another question follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759067/vnet-peering-and-private-dns-zone

Answer (score 2):

I have created two virtual network same one for Virtual machine and another for Storage account and peered like below:

[image]

When I check `nslookup` on storage account from VM I got the same public Ip address like below:

[image]

To resolve this issue, check the below steps:

In Private DNS Zone under setting virtual network link add virtual machine vnet like below:

[image]

Now when I check `nslookup` I got storage account private IP address:

```c
nslookup strimr8xxx.blob.core.windows.net
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  168.63.129.16

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    strimr88xxx.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net
Address:  172.0.0.x
Aliases:  strimr8xxx.blob.core.windows.net
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @imran for the detailed response. We did come across with this solution but the problem is we have multiple resource group with VNET having storage account and can't implement this solution. For e.g VM is VNET1, SA1 in VNET2 and SA2 in VNET3. We can only associate VNET1 with Private DNS under for SA1 or SA2(by the way we have Private DNS for each SA in different Resource Group)

Also what we noticed that even if it gives public IP address we can do all the operation on storage account with public access disabled. We think its because of successful paring.

Comment: Another follow up question would be if the storage account's public access is disable(blob anonymous access disabled) and nslookup returns public ip address how we are able to perform operations(upload blob/create container) on storage account from VM?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati please raise a new question with detail and screenshot

Comment: @Imran Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759067/vnet-peering-and-private-dns-zone