# VNET Peering and Private DNS zone

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

I have very specific question and hope to get some answers.

Below is my situation,

- I have three VNET.
- VNET1: Has storage account with public access disabled(blob anonymous access disabled). The same VNET has VM
- VNET2: Has VM and VNET1 and VNET2 is peered
- VNET3: Has one VM

Question:
When I do nslookup from VM in VNET1 I get private IP address(which is expected). When I do nslookup from VM in VNET2 I get public IP address(which is also expected as per the response I got from another post [Azure VNet peering with Private Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753511/azure-vnet-peering-with-private-link)). The solution I got is to add VNET link in Private DNS zone.

The real question I have is why I am able to perform all operations(upload blob/create container) from VM IN VNET2 even after getting public IP address for nslookup for storage account?

Also created diagram with my topology as well

[image]

Below is my network config for storage account
[image]

Update: Adding updated diagram with all resources in resource group.
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the network configuration of your storage account?

Comment: I guess VM2 doesn't use your VPN

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot No it doesn't. Its in its own VNET and not on public ip.

Comment: My first thought was DNS propagation time. Is this possible?

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot Also VM in VNET3 has the same config except its not peered and we can't perform any operation on storage account.

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot Could you please elaborate on "DNS propagation time"?

Comment: Sorry, I misused "DNS propagation time". I meant "DNS cache" on the VM. This makes no sense, since the private DNS link is not linked to this VNET 2 ("vnet-vm").

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you check if the network diagram generated by VNET is similar to the one you drew?

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot I added new diagram generated by Azure(from resource visualizer). Previous diagram was also from resource visualizer but I removed some of the resource so it can be less crowded.

Comment: Can you check from the network watcher the next hop of your VM in VNET2 to the IP returned by nslookup?

Comment: And in firewall if you use your VPN or added public Ip address of ur machine 'yes' you can able to perform all operations [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: So I recreated everything and now its working as expected and I am unable to connect to Storage Account from VNET2. The reason for it is the note on one of the Microsoft article. Thanks everyone for helping me on this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#change-the-default-network-access-rule

Comment: "By design, access to a storage account from trusted services takes the highest precedence over other network access restrictions. If you set Public network access to Disabled after previously setting it to Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses, any resource instances and exceptions that you previously configured, including Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account, will remain in effect. As a result, those resources and services might still have access to the storage account."

Comment: Glad that issue is fixed posting an answer to help other community members who encounter same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MsDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759067/vnet-peering-and-private-dns-zone?noredirect=1#comment137097877_77759067)

> By design, access to a storage account from trusted services takes the highest precedence over other network access restrictions. If you set  **Public network access**  to  **Disabled**  after previously setting it to  **Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses**, any  [resource instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-azure-resource-instances) and  [exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#manage-exceptions) that you previously configured, including  [Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-trusted-azure-services), will remain in effect. As a result, those resources and services might still have access to the storage account.

[image]

This means that if you previously granted access to a storage account from trusted services, such as Azure services or specific virtual networks and IP addresses, and then later disabled public network access to the storage account, the trusted services and virtual networks the previous configurations for trusted services might still be in effect.

[image]

In your case, it seems that the trusted services were granted access to the storage account from VNET2 before you disabled public network access to the storage account. This is why you were still able to access the storage account from VNET2 even though public network access was disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The behavior is so strange and I wish Microsoft fix this soon.